# Create Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i'm wondering if it's possible to define an array of parameters (sorry dunno how it's called) like in jQuery also in php:

```
{myCaption: 'bla', myValue: 123 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arry = array('myCaption'=>"bla",'myValue'=>123);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll get the same result using in PHP:

```
$A=array ("myCaption"=>"bla","myValue"=>123);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

you could always take objects in PHP and turn them into JSON

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

and from JSON into PHP with:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Barewords? Are you serious? Never do that. This is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create an [object](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)? Easy:

```
$obj = array(
    'key' => 'someValue',
    'anotherKey' => 23
);
```

Is 'equivalent' to:

```
var obj = {
    key: 'someValue',
    anotherKey: 23
};
```

Note however, you are refering to 'as in jQuery'. Don't forget jQuery is just a library!

You could also create class in PHP which holds your values:

```
class A
{
    public $myValue;

    public function __construct($myValue)
    {
         $this->myValue = $myValue;
    }
}

$obj = new A(23);
echo $obj->myValue; // 23
```

See the following [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) for some more information on classes.

Comment: That's not an object, it's an associative array. A true object would be created by: `$obj = new stdClass; $obj->key = 'someValue';` and so on.

Comment: @Martin Bean: You're right. It might not be clear but, I meant that he would like to create a javascript 'object' in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, it is called an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals). jQuery is just a JS library, it isn't a language.

The PHP equivalent is an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

```
$foo = array( "myCaption" => 'bla', "myValue" => 123 );
```

Comment: This isn't valid syntax, it should be `$foo = array('myCaption' => 'bla', 'myValue' => 123);`

Comment: AFAIK, PHP does not have a `Array` object. Arrays are initialized using the `array()` function.

Comment: @rudi: the syntax is the same as what is given in the manual.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: Right, but that is because the author corrected his post. The old version was incorrect. My and @rudi_visser's comments refer to that old version.

Comment: @matt Where in the manual?? Here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php, it shows `$arr = array("foo" => "bar", 12 => true);`

Comment: @elusive: oh, fair enough. I didn't see the earlier version. Ninja edits are too easy to do at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can. It's something like JSON syntax so you could do something like that:

```
var_dump(json_decode("{'myCaption': 'bla', 'myValue': 123 }", true));
```

But that's ugly way :)

Comment: This is not valid JSON. JSON's keys and values (except for numbers, booleans or null) need to be wrapped in double quotes (`"`).

Comment: And the code returns `NULL` because that isn't JSON you are trying to decode.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you posted is an object literal (as named a literal form of defining an object), this can also be done more explicitly in Javascript and as mentioned before, jQuery is a framework/library, and *not* a language.

To define the same array in PHP you would do:

```
$array = array('myCaption' => 'bla', 'myValue' => 123);
```

An object literal is almost directly conforment to JSON and as such which minor modifications can be passed through to the `json_decode` method, allowing you get an array out of this.

It works like this (modifications included):

```
$js_str = '{"myCaption": "bla", "myValue": "123"}';
$obj = json_decode($js_str, true);
```

You can also go back the other way like so:

```
$array = array('myCaption' => 'bla', 'myValue' => 123);
$js_str = json_encode($array);
```

Comment: No. It isn't JSON because (a) It doesn't meet the syntax rules and (b) The question stated it was in JavaScript (and it isn't quoted as a string).

Comment: Yes, it is a data serialisation format which conforms to a subset of JavaScript. The data in the question doesn't conform to that subset. The actual literal definition of an object in JavaScript is "an object literal" not "JSON".

Comment: Because the string you pass to `json_decode` isn't valid, you don't get any data in `$obj`

Comment: @David My apologies, you're correct, I did not intend to post JSON however an object literal as you correctly named. I updated my answer to reflect how a slightly modified version of the OP's string can be used as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, in Javascript this is called a object literal, now it can be created within php but it cannot be used like an array, you can create a object literal using `json_encode`, for example:

```
//Create an array
$json = array(
    "myCaption" => 'bla',
    "myValue" => 123
);

//Convert it to a PHP Object
$data = (object)$data;

//Get the results in an json stricg:
$result = json_encode($data);

echo $result;
```

this should return something along the lines of: `{myCaption: 'bla', myValue: 123 }`, it amy wrapped in an array thought, not 100% sure but you may get `[{myCaption: 'bla', myValue: 123 }]` instead.

Comment: In JavaScript, it is called an **object literal**, not a [JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: an associative array or an object. A lot of the previous examples show you have to create an array:

```
$obj = array(
    'key' => 'someValue',
    'foo' => 'bar',
    'baz' => 'somethingElse'
);
```

Or you can create a true object:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->key = 'someValue';
$obj->foo = 'bar';
$obj->baz = 'somethingElse';
```